# Typescript generic object with index signature properties strongly typed

Tags: typescript, generics, types, interface

I would like to define a Typescript generic object with a property strongly typed depending on the index signature value.

It will be something like

```
type ObjectProps<T> = {
    [ K: string ]: Typename<T> === K? Partial<T> : unknown
}
```

In case `K` is the type name of `T`, I want `K` values to be of type `Partial<T>` otherwise, I want it to be of type `unknown`.

Use case:

```
interface Test {
  prop: string
}

const a: ObjectProps<Test> = someDatasource()

const b1 = a.Test        // b will be of type Partial<Test>
const b2 = b1.prop       // valid TS 
const b3 = b1.otherProp  // invalid TS
const c = a.otherProp    // c will be of type unknown
```

Is it that possible? Any workaround?

Comment: What is `Typename`?  There is no relationship in TypeScript between types and the names that are used to refer to them; TypeScript's type system is structural and not nominal (`interface Foo {a: string}` and `interface Bar {a: string}` are the same type) , and some types do not even have names (you can write `{a: string}` as an anonymous type), so I'm not quite sure what you're going for.  Maybe some fixed enumeration of mappings from names to types?  Please consider writing a [mcve] with how you would use such an `ObjectProps<T>` so someone can test a solution against well-defined test cases.

Comment: @jcalz I know that TS types in compile time are in another world than TS/JS runtime, but there are some forms of types in TS very near to what I'm asking such as
```ts 
export type ClassMethodNames<T> = {
 [ K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function? K : never
}[keyof T]
```
On the other hand, `Typename` is a hypothetical helper type.

Comment: `ClassMethodNames` is different, because those names exist as property keys at runtime.  Meanwhile, your `Test` name does not, unless you explicitly provide that name.  You can write out an explicit name mapping somewhere, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mplVxm).    If this meets your needs I can write up an answer; otherwise the answer is just "no, this is impossible". Let me know.